# Trying to fix the background image on label:checked

Tags: css

I'm trying to fix something another developer did on this site: http://alamodecreamery.com/products-page/accessories/girls-atom/

If you hover over the sizes a waffle icon appears, however when the item is checked (radio button) the background disappears. I need a label:checked background to show the waffle. I found the CSS selector on line 1150 of wpsc-default.css and added a label:active for testing which works fine (aqua on active).

Can anyone figure out why the :checked background isnt working? Ive tried a few different things which all failed to work:

```
label + input[type="radio"]:checked { 
    background:pink !important;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked { 
    background:pink !important;
}

.wpsc_variation_forms label:checked {background-color: green !important;}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting cannot work. You have a structure in which the radio `input` is contained inside the `label`. The `label` is sized to match the waffle, and on hover changes its background. When the radio button is checked, the `input` gets the `:checked` state, not the `label`! And in CSS, right now, it is regrettably not possible to [select an element based on a descendant's state](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/). As such, it is not possible with pure CSS to change the appearance of the `label` based on a pseudoclass of one of its contained elements.

I would recommend adding a bit of Javascript which toggles a class on the `label` when the radio button is toggled, would be the easiest fix.

---

Techy sidenote: there have been multiple proposals in the past for 'parent selectors', and all have been shot down by the browser developers because it was unfeasible from a performance perspective due to the way the DOM and CSS are matched up. Nowadays the engines are so efficient the discussion has been restarted, but still in very preliminary stage. Don't expect anything before CSS4 surfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will look into a js solution. Although CSS would be preferred

Answer (score 0):

label:checked is invalid. checked is for inputs only.

Something like

```
wpsc_variation_forms label + input:checked
```

might work better

Comment: Cannot work since the `input` is inside the `label`. `+` is for [selecting adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Comment: And also this will not target the label.